# if else "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'" error

Tags: if-statement, swiftui

The following code generates the "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'" error, but why?

```
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        if isLineGraph == true {
            chartAverage()  <- Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'
        } else {
            chartActual()
        }
```

If I change chartAverage() to chartActual() you get the same error. Don't understand why I am getting the error and if I am why it doesn't generate them against both functions?

Example of chartAverage()

```
func chartAverage() {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var scheme
    var cloudCoverArray: [CloudCoverArray] = GlobalVariables.masterCloudCover
    Chart {
        ForEach(cloudCoverArray, id:\.self) {item in
            LineMark(
                x: .value("Date", item.date),
                y: .value("CloudCover", item.averageCloud),
                series: .value("Date", "CloudCover")
            )
            .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
            .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
        }
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(width: GlobalVariables.screenWidth - 32, height: 340 + 30)  // 30 = top + bottom padding from CalculateView
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
    //.padding()
    .background {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
            .fill((scheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white).shadow(.drop(radius: 2)))
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the implementation (or at least the signature) of `chartAverage()` and `chartActual()`, it's not possible to answer without that.

Comment: You cannot run arbitrary code  in the rendering area of a SwiftUI view unless the code returns a SwiftUI `View`.

Comment: Code added to original question.

Comment: Have change start of func to:  @ViewBuilder
func chartAverage()->some View{ and that works. Is that the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chartAverage()` and `chartActual()` must both return `View` types, typically `some View`. Without this, the view builder fails at the first error it encounters, and you don't get an error for the second mistake.

You have this:

```swift
func chartAverage() {
```

You need this:

```swift
func chartAverage() -> some View {
```

Comment: That's what I did but I also seemed to needed to add @ViewBuilder on the line above the function to make it work - does that make sense?

Comment: @Environment inside a function isn't going to work. That should be a property of your view struct, as should the first variable. You only need the view builder annotation if you are returning multiple separate views or don't want to have an explicit return.